# Kotlin: Get null of a PROCEDURE CALL with an INSERT

Tags: sql, kotlin, null, return-value, procedure

I'm trying to get the result of an SQL PROCEDURE like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProcedure]
    @varTest INT,
    @varTest2 INT
AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @returnValue AS INT

    SET @returnValue = 1234
    
    INSERT INTO xTABLE(col1, col2)
    VALUES(1, 2)

    SELECT @returnValue AS returnValue 
    RETURN
    
END
GO
```

And I've this Kotlin code

```
val statement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL TestProcedure (1, 1)}")
statement.execute()
val rs = statement.resultSet
```

And the resultSet is null

But if I delete the part of INSERT SQL, I've the resultSet with returnValue = 1234, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may be getting multiple result sets?  *(One for the INSERT, which is empty but associates with metadata telling you that 1 row was affected, and a second for the SELECT.)*  You could try to acquire the second result set with `rs = statement.getResultSet()` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-retrieve-multiple-resultsets-from-a-stored-procedure-using-a-jdbc-program

Comment: Thanks for the info @MatBailie, I got the solution doing statement.getMoreResults() and then I can get the correct ResultSet with the return of the procedure call